# Execute javascript function from hidden field

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'm using XSLT to create a javascript function using the XML data from the member. I would like to be able to execute this function from a `<script>` element in the template, if it's possible.

How the javascript function is created:

```
<XSL:variable name="ScriptToAdd">
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"> 
    <XSL:text>displayBigSuppPub('</XSL:text>
    <XSL:value-of select="$suppPubPath" />
    <XSL:text>', '</XSL:text>
    <XSL:value-of select="$member/multiplePubs/multiplePub/@name" />
    <XSL:text>');</XSL:text>
</script>
</XSL:variable>

<input type="hidden" id="scriptToAdd" value="{$ScriptToAdd}" />
```

When I check in the source code, I can see that javascript function in the hidden field value.

I have a `<script>` element in my template that is used to change between the profile tabs and I would like to execute the function in the hidden field when the Publicity tab is selected.

```
if(sTab == "publicites") {
    scriptAdded = document.getElementById('scriptToAdd').value;
    alert(scriptAdded);
}
```

This works when I change to the Pubs tab but I don't know how and if I can execute this code instead of using alert (alert is used only as a test).

The javascript function I want to execute:

```
displayBigSuppPub('getImage.php?path=resources/images/members/21214/Tulips.jpg&canvasWidth=640', 'Tulips.jpg');
```

This function works correctly when used with a onclick event on the member's publicities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` should do (but is not a really nice solution)
Try:

```
if(sTab == "publicites") {
    scriptAdded = document.getElementById('scriptToAdd').value;
    eval(scriptAdded);
}
```

This has nothing to do with xlst, but any way.

If you do it this way there is not need for:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
```

Comment: Works fine. Could you explain why it's not a nice solution? I'd like to know for knowledge purposes.